# How to find user groups using facebook graph api v2.4

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to get list of groups with their id and name using the graph api v2.4. I have tried this  in graph api v2.3 and it gets list of groups with thieir ids and names. However it returns empty array data in v2.4.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me/groups?fields=id,name
```

returns

```
{
  "data": [
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get a list of groups you manage, with the `user_managed_groups` permission and the `/me/groups` endpoint.

`user_groups` is deprecated, as you can read in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4